# Copying cell value to textbox vba

Tags: vba, excel, object, textbox

I have been trying to write a macro that will dynamically fill a textbox on a new sheet will the value of a cell from another sheet.

I have managed to get it working using this:

```
Sub copyDetail()

' Define variables

Dim pre As Worksheet
Dim des As Worksheet

Set pre = Sheets("Presentation")
Set des = Sheets("Description")

Dim i As Integer
Dim lbl As String

' Scroll through labels and copy where boolean = 1

For i = 2 To 17
    If des.Cells(i, 2) = 1 Then
        lbl = des.Cells(i, 11)
        Sheets("Presentation").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).Select
        Selection.Text = lbl

    Else

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I basically want to be able to do exactly what this does but without using select all the time as this changes sheets and slows down my code (I have many other sub's to run alongside this one). I've tried things like defining the textbox using this:

```
Dim myLabel As Object
Set myLabel = pre.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1"))
```

But then I get an "object doesn't support this property or method" error when I try and call:

```
myLabel.Text = lbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the text of a `TextBox` like so:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello world"
```

You can set-up a little helper `Sub` in a `Module` to make the code re-usable:

```
Public Sub SetTextBoxText(ws As Worksheet, strShapeName As String, strText As String)

    Dim shp As Shape

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = ws.Shapes(strShapeName)

    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = strText
    Else
        Debug.Print "Shape not found"
    End If

End Sub
```